# Explicação para o erro no seguinte código

Tags: c#

Comecei a resolver os problemas do projeto Euler como forma de treino na aprendizagem.

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

Este é o enunciado. Decidi personizalar a minha resposta, acrescentando mais alguns detalhes no código.

O código é:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
            
int[] x= new int[10];
int Tot=0;
      
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{  
    if ((i%3==0)||(i%5==0)) 
    {    
        x[i] = i;
        Console.WriteLine(x[i]);         
    }
                    
    Console.WriteLine(Tot+=x[i]);
```

Executando o código, vai mostrar apenas os multiplos de 3 e 5 no intervalo 0 a 10: 3,5,6,9

Quando acrescento o somatorio do array, em vez de dar o número total, 23, apresenta esta lista: 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 5 8 6 14 14 14 9 23.

Por que? Por que é que não retorna apenas o número 23?

Answer (score 1):

[Transformei seu código em um Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2Maw3R).

Repare que isso:

```
Console.WriteLine(Tot+=x[i]);
```

Está dentro do `for`, então será impresso a cada nova iteração.

Outra coisa é que você não está atribuindo `Tot` nesta linha. Apenas está escrevendo o resultado da soma de `Tot` com `x[i]`. Como não está atribuindo, o resultado se perde.

Modifiquei seu código para:

```
    int[] x= new int[10];
    int Tot=0;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {  
        if ((i%3==0)||(i%5==0)) 
        {    
            x[i] = i;
            // Console.WriteLine(x[i]);    
            Tot += x[i]; // Aqui temos uma atribuição correta
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(Tot); // Fiz imprimir o resultado fora do for
```

Veja que a resposta, no canto inferior da tela, é 23.